# How can I config `version` param for composer?

Tags: composer-php

I want to get `https://github.com/mark-rolich/Event.js` by composer.
I add this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"package",
        "package": {
            "name": "mark-rolich/event.js",
            "version": "*",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/mark-rolich/Event.js",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

When run `composer require mark-rolich/event.js` command.
give me this error:

```
  [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
  A repository of type "package" contains an invalid package definition: Invalid package information:
  version : invalid value (*): Invalid version string "*"
  Invalid package definition:
  {"name":"mark-rolich\/event.js","version":"*","source":{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/mark-rolich\/Event.js","type":"git","reference":"master"}}


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

How can I config `version` param for this package?

Answer (score 0):

Download that file you are interested in, and add it to your own repository. That's way easier that trying to make Composer download something that it isn't meant to do in the first place:

- Composer was built to manage PHP packages, which are not required to be placed in a particular directory.
- Using packages will hugely benefit from `composer.json` files being present, and having the repository being registered on packagist.org
- In order to install Javascript packages, which require being placed into a certain directory, you'd have to use some additional plugins.
- Also there is an existing toolchain for Javascript to do just the same thing that Composer does for PHP: Bower or npm.

You want to use a package that consists of only one single code file that hasn't changed in the last 4 years. I'd consider it very unlikely it will change in the future - so there isn't even a benefit from using a package manager. Just be sure you stick to the license restrictions for this code when copying.